# Sharepoint 2010 http webapp redirected to wrong webapp when using https

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping, ssl

I am facing a specific probelm on a Server2008R2 & Sharepoint 2010 setup.
On the System there are multiple Webapps, but only one must be configured with SSL on port 443. the others remain on port 80 and http. (all with the same IP)

e.g.:
https// xx.sp2010:443
http// ab.sp2010:80

I have successfully configured https on https:// xx.sp2010.
Whenever users accidently  access https:// ab.sp2010 (although not configured) they get redirected to https://xx.sp2010 (because its the only site listening on 443 on that IP)
I have to figure out a way to prevent sharepoint &/or IIS to redirect from one webapp to the other.

I have configured many sharepoint deploymets with http and https, but usually i go for dedicated IP and certificates on all webapps.

This time the customer just wants 1 Webapp to be reachable via https.

Am i missing some configurations in the AAM?

- "http:// ab:8080"   Default
- "http:// xx.ab"     Default
- "https:// xx.ab443"  Intranet
- "http:// ab"        Default
- "http:// yy.ab"    Default--> when accessing this webapp with https i get redirected to "https:// xx.ab"
- "http:// ab:2010"   Default

Comment: could you please share your AAM settings from Central admin. lookalike you are redirecting their.

Comment: hello, thx for the comment, but am i missing something in your question? redirecting their .. ?